# packaged build missing winston package for child process

Tags: electron-forge

My app has a nodejs app started using fork() - the nodejs app is added to the build using the 'extraResource' option

When I run using 'npm start', it works fine, as does running the built exe in the 'out' folder

When I copy all the files into another directory, it complains "cannot find module 'winston'" for my child process

My main.js app uses winston and still works file - I can see a log file created with entries prior to the point it does the fork() and then the child process crashes with the above error

All the other npm packages are found ok

If I do 'npm install winston' in the new directory, then everything works, so all the other npm packages are found ok (like serialport, jsonfile, socket.io etc..)

Why the build exe appears to selectively omit 'winston' for the child process is beyond me

I'm guessing it's because it's a child process adding using 'extraResource' - but not a clue why or more importantly, how to fix it - anyone have any ideas?

Extract from my package.json...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cbuslibrary": "^2.7.5",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "jsonfile": "^6.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "openurl": "^1.1.1",
    "serialport": "^12.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.4",
    "winston": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.2.0",
    "electron": "28.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: tried setting prune:false in forge.config.js in packagerConfig, but that hasn't made any difference